# Get text value from XAML TextBox (Login_Page.xaml) and set to XAML TextBlock (Menu_Page.xaml)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro

im doing an online game for Windows 8 Modern UI. Ive got Login_Page XAML file with textboxes for Login and Password. Text from Login TextBox after log in has to be displayed in another XAML file (Menu_Page.xaml) as a nickname of player and also will suggesting to server which player account it is to display other things like: Experience, Level, Game_Rank. 
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Ive tried to make this object visible in MainPage class and opposite but i read somewhere, when you create object of main class in metro apps the function InitializeComponent() is called so all xaml element of this class are set to null.

Ive tried this:
page = new MenuPage();
page.textBlock.Text = this.loginbox.Text;
but its null i think so nothing will show.

to navigate to MenuPage xaml page from LoginPage i use this:
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MenuPage));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only having one player on each client you could set the user class to a static class and then call that from each page.

e.g

```
public static class Player
{
   public static string nickname{get; set;}
   //ect
}
```

then when you want to use it.

```
Player.nickname = "myname";
```

Comment: Like for example this:
<code>
public class Player
{
  public string nick_name {get;set;}
  public int lvl {get;set;}
  public int exp {get;set;}
}
// set some string to nick_name
Player player = new Player();
player.nick_name = "text from loginbox or string"?

//in other .cs file:
Player player = new Player();
nick_nameBox.Text = player.nick_name; //Here i got error: Value cannot be null.
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a static class to store the shared values then accessing those values when needed. For example, you could create a static class `SharedValues` with the property `UserName`. After login, set the username using `SharedValues.UserName = "username"`. Then in the `MenuPage`, just get the username. i.e. `this.textBlock.Text = Sharedvalues.UserName`.

SharedValues class:

```
public class SharedValues
{
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this.textBlock.Text = Sharedvalues.UserName 
Ive always get error here which said Sharedvalues.UserName "Value cannot be null."